# Better way to distribute releases

Tags: android, ios, release

I make the APK and IPA build for the weekly releases and I upload them to dropbox and send the link to the customer.
Is there any other better-automated way to share the final IPA / APK file with the customer?

Comment: Better asked on http://android.stackexchange.com/ or http://apple.stackexchange.com/ as it is about app deployment and not testing.

Comment: But why,release management is also a part of QA roal.

Comment: The quality of the release management maybe, but not the how do I ship to customers. You could argue that the whole SDLC is part of QA. Other SE's probably have more experience with releases ande delivery of mobile apps. Is this a task you would let your tester do, sounds more DevOps or Operations? Even if it was ontopic then the question is too broad or opinionated, because what is better?.

Answer (score 1):

For beta distribution, you can use for example fabric.io (free), and upload binaries with gradle (android) and Fastlane (ios). If you configure fabric in your apps, you have also dashboards with crashes, and much more data.

Configuration for gradle (Android):
[Distribution with Gradle](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html)

Configuration for fastlane (iOS):
[Upload a new build to Crashlytics Beta](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/#crashlytics)

You can also use this on Continous Integration system, what I recommend.

Comment: Just now i tryed with fabric ,But for that i had to add some binary to my build so it is not going to work.Let me try with others.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't like "what's the best tool for" questions, but the answer to this is too good to ignore [hockeyapp](https://hockeyapp.net/)

After simple registration apps are pushed to your device.